# Persist custom list<string> property of datagridviewcolumn

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, propertygrid, designmode

I have a WinForm application with a customized `DataGridViewColumn` with 1 added property, a simple `List<string>`. I can change it to whatever sort of collection will make it work, if needed. The problem I am having is that when I set the property in the Designer, it does not persist. When I click OK and then go back into it, it is blank again. I have done extensive research and tried everything I can find but it does this no matter what.

The latest try is below:

```
[TypeConverterAttribute(typeof(System.ComponentModel.ExpandableObjectConverter))]
public class MyCustomColumn : DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
{
    [Editor("System.Windows.Forms.Design.StringCollectionEditor,System.Design",
     "System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor, System.Drawing")]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    [Description("My custom property")]
    public List<string> MyListOfStrings {get;set;}

    public MyCustomColumn()
    {
        this.CellTemplate = new MyCustomCell();
        MyListOfStrings = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom property won't save when changed in property window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10816916/custom-property-wont-save-when-changed-in-property-window)

Comment: Yes, the fix mentioned there worked!